# excel evaluate destination cells before pasting over

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Hello clever people.

I manage a group workbook; each sheet has time series data, in one row per month.  I receive excel sheets updated with an extra row for the latest month's data.  After some rudimentary checks, I paste the new sheet over the existing sheet, so newer data is now added lower down the page.

Sometimes, a value in a row for an earlier month has changed in the imported sheet - sometimes by accident but often after validation.  Obviously, when I paste on the latest sheet, only the most recent value is present - I don't necessarily need the old value, I just need to know its been changed.

I thought of performing a checksum on each row, before and after - that would do to indicate a change.  Any ideas of a straightforward approach?

TIA, Paul

Comment: Maybe just add in an extra column in your new sheet before copying / pasting with a formula along the lines of `=Sum(this_row) - Sum(This_row in other workbook)` and filter for non-zeros? You could even use conditional formatting to highlight the changed values in this case... The main point being to do it BEFORE pasting over your old values, though....

Answer (score 0):

If values to check are numbers only you could paste it special with substraction, non-changed cells would become zeros...